# Cassandra - DataStax OpsCenter: Error provisioning cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I install Cassandra on my local mac, together with opscenter from DataStax. When I create the new cluster, it gives me the error,

"Error
Error provisioning cluster: Unable to login to some nodes. Please check your user/creds"

though I am very sure "Node Credentials (sudo)" user name and password are entered correctly. Any idea?

The server side logs show,

```
"2015-06-02 17:00:48+0800 []  INFO: Sleeping before retrying ssh login.
2015-06-02 17:00:53+0800 [] There was a problem verifying an ssh login on 127.0.0.1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: opscenterd.SecureShell.SshFailed: ssh to u'127.0.0.1' failed"
```

However, when I open a terminal and try ssh username@127.0.0.1. I can access without a problem

Comment: Please share the following files from Opscenter: `opscenterd.conf`, and `cluster.conf`. Then from the agent the `address.yaml`. Also please post the end few lines of the `cassandra.yaml` file listing the server and client encryption option. Thanks.